# Implementing a menu like device without conditionals for each command

Tags: c

Suppose I'm trying to implement a "menu" of sorts that asks the user to enter a command and then calls the function that executes that command. Instead of having a block of conditionals for each command, I decided to declare an array of strings that contains each command name and then compares the user's input with the strings in that array to see what to do next.

Something like:

```
char* commands[] = {"cmd", "cmd1", "cmd2"};
```

Then:

```
while(strcmp(cmd, "end") != MATCH) {

    printf("?:");
    scanf("%s", cmd);

    for(i = 0; i < CMD_NUMBER; i++) {
        if(strcmp(cmd, commands[i]) == MATCH) {
            /*do something */

        }   
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call the function without having any conditionals or switch statements at this point? I was thinking of implementing a struct of function pointers, with a member for each command, and then using that, but I'm not exactly sure how or if that's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a struct that contains both the command and a pointer to the function:

```
typedef struct {
    char * cmd;
    void (* func)();
} Command_t;

Command_t commands[] = {
    "cmd", func_cmd,
    "cmd2", func_cmd2
};
```

Note: You need to *declare* the functions above this structure, else your compiler will balk at them.

(Edit) Just for completeness, you'd use this structure as

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(commands)/sizeof(commands[0]); i++)
{
    if(!strcmp(cmd, commands[i].cmd))
    {
        commands[i].func();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit curious though as to how the addresses of the functions are assigned like that, more specifically I guess I'm wondering when the linker assigns memory addresses for functions and then how does that come into play with an initialization of an array such as this?

Comment: It Just Does. There is nothing special about function names in this regard.